# Branch to an address using GCC inline ARM asm

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, inline-assembly

I want to `branch` to a particular address(NOT a label) using `ARM assembly`, without modifying the `LR` register. So I go with `B` instead of `BL` or `BX`.
I want this to be done in `GCC inline asm`.

[Here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Cihfddaf.html) is the documentation, and here is what I 've tried:

```
#define JMP(addr) \
    __asm__("b %0" \
            : /*output*/ \
            : /*input*/ \
            "r" (addr) \
           );
```

It is a C macro, that can be called with an `address`. When I run it I get the following error:

`error: undefined reference to 'r3'`

The error is because of the usage of `"r"`. I looked into it a bit, and I've found that it could be a bug on gcc 4.9.* version.

BTW, I am using `Android/Linux Gcc 4.9 cross compiler`, on an `OSX`.
Also, I don't know wether I should have loaded something on `Rm`.

Cheers!

**Edit:**
I changed the macro to this, and I still get `undefined reference to r3 and r4`:

```
#define JMP(addr) \
    __asm__("LDR r5,=%0\n\t" \
            "LDR r4,[r5]\n\t"\
            "ADD r4,#1\n\t" \
            "B r4" \
            : /*output*/ \
            : /*input*/ \
            "r" (addr) \
            : /*clobbered*/ \
            "r4" ,"r5" \
           );
```

Explanation:
load the address of the variable to r5, then load the value of that address to r4. Then add 1 to LSB (emm required by ARM specification?). And finally Branch to that address.

Comment: "The LDR pseudo-instruction loads a register with either: a 32-bit constant value or an address." So in your case compiler thinks rX is a symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't branch to a register, you can only branch to a label. If you want to jump to address in a register you need to move it into the PC register (r15).

```
#define JMP(addr) \
    __asm__("mov pc,%0" \
            : /*output*/ \
            : /*input*/ \
            "r" (addr) \
           );
```

Comment: I 've written something similar a couple of minutes ago, but I haven't tested it yet! Lets hope that it works!
Btw, since it is `gcc asm` pc and %0 should swap in your example!

Comment: I don't think they should be swapped. With ARM GCC uses the standard ARM operand ordering. You may be thinking of x86 targets where GCC uses a non-standard order.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are programming in C, you could just use a plain C approach without any assembly at all: just cast the variable, that holds the pointer to address to which you want to jump, to a function pointer and call it right away:

```
((void (*)(void)) addr)();
```

just an explanation to this jungle of brackets:
with this code you are casting `addr` to a pointer (signified by the star `(*)`) to a function that takes no argument (the second `void` means there are no arguments) and that also returns nothing (first `void`). finally the last two brackets are the actual invocation of that function.
Google for "C function pointer" for more information about that approach.

But if that doesn't work for you and you still want to go with the assembly approach, the instruction that you are in looking for is in fact `BX` (not sure why you excluded that initially. but I can guess that the name "Branch and Exchange" mislead you to believe that the register argument is swapped (and thereby changed) with the program counter, which is *NOT* the case, but it confused me in the beginning, too).

For that just a simple recap of the instructions:

- `B` would take a label as an argument. Actually the jump will be encoded as an offset from the current position, which tells the processor to jump that many instruction forwards or backwards (normally the compiler, assembler or linker will take care of calculating that offset for you). During execution, control flow will simply be transferred to that position *without* changing any register (this means also the link register `LR` will stay unchanged)
- `BX R0` will take the absolute (so *not* an offset) address from a register, in this case `R0`, and continue execution at that address. This is also done *without* changing any other register.
- `BL` and `BLX R0` are the corresponding counterparts to the previous two instruction. They will do the same thing control flow wise, but on top of that save the current program counter in the link register `LR`. This is needed if the called function is supposed to return later on.

so in essence, what you would need to do is:

```
asm("BX %0" : : "r"(addr));
```

instructing the compiler to make sure the variable `addr` is in a register (`r`), which you are promising to only read and not to change. on top of that, upon return you won't have changed (clobbered) any other register.

See here
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constraints.html
for more information about inline assembly constraints.

To help you understand why there are also other solutions floating around, here some things about the ARM architecture:

- the program counter `PC` is for many instruction accessible as a regular register `R15`. It's just an alias for that exact register number.
- this means that almost all arithmetic and register altering instructions can take it as an argument. However, for many of them it is highly deprecated.
- if you are looking at the disassembly of a program compiled to ARM code, any function will end with one of three things:

  - `BX LR` which does exactly what you want to do: take the content of the link register (`LR` is an alias for `R14`) and jump to that location, effectively returning to the caller
  - `POP {R4-R11, PC}` restoring the caller saved register and jumping back to the caller. This will almost certainly have counterpart of `PUSH {R4-R11, LR}` in the beginning of the function: your are pushing the content of the link register (the return address) onto the stack but store it back into the program counter effectively returning to the caller in the end
  - `B` branch to a different function, if this function ends with a tail call and leaving it up to that function to return to the original caller.

Hope that helps,
Martin